# How to filter the result where >80% of the transaction coming from the same customer?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction table like this:

```
tr_id    merchant customer  amount
-------------------------------------
00001    2005     3002      20
00002    2006     3002      11.16
00003    2001     3007      17.91
00004    2005     3002      20
00005    2003     3003      13.23
00005    2006     3007      14.61
00006    2005     3002      20 
Etc.
```

I want to know the query to find which merchant that have >80% of the transaction coming from the same customer.

The result should contain list of merchant, customer in question, and each with sum of amount.

Comment: show your expected output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select c.merchant, customer, 100 * customer_total / merchant_total as percentage
from (select merchant, customer, sum(amount) as customer_total
    from mytable
    group by merchant, customer) c
join (select merchant, sum(amount) as merchant_total
    from mytable
    group by merchant) m 
    on m.merchant = c.merchant
      and customer_total > .8 * merchant_total
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7149de/2).

You could change `and` to `where` if you feel it improves readability, at a possible small cost to performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Group the table once by `merchant` to calculate the total records of
   each `merchant`
2. Once again, group the table by `merchant` and `customer` to calculate
   the total records of each merchant and customer
3. Join the result and calculate the percentage

query :

```
SELECT
       t2.merchant,
       t2.customer,
       CONCAT((CAST(t2.merchant_Customer_CuontItem AS FLOAT) / CAST(t1.merchant_CuontItem AS FLOAT)) * 100, '%') AS newCol
FROM    
  (SELECT merchant,COUNT(*) AS merchant_CuontItem FROM tb GROUP BY merchant) t1    
JOIN     
  (SELECT merchant,customer ,COUNT(*) AS merchant_Customer_CuontItem FROM tb GROUP BY merchant,customer) t2     
ON t1.merchant = t2.merchant
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bcc410a11067932f385fe7b16835bdd)